# Multiple injection across same activity lifecycle results in multiple instances

Tags: android, dependency-injection, scope, dagger-2, activity-lifecycle

There is this injector for the MainActivity defined as below in a module that is referenced by the ApplicationComponent:

```
@PerActivity
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = MainActivityModule.class)
abstract MainActivity mainActivityInjector();
```

and the MainActivityModule referenced by the contributor looks like this:

```
@Module
public class MainActivityModule {

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    public MyActivityDependency myActivityDependency() {
        return new MyActivityDependency();
    }
}
```

and the MainActivity itself is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    MyActivityDependency myActivityDependency;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        Log.d(myActivityDependency.hashCode());
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        Log.d(myActivityDependency.hashCode());
        ...
}
```

The @PerActivity Scope is supposed to preserve Activity’s dependency instances throughout its lifecycle.

This basically means that if I perform injection (AndroidInjection.inject(this)) multiple times, I am entitled to get the same injected instance (at least that's the goal).

In that case, why different instances of the MyDependency is injected each time the “.inject()” method is called?

Answer (score 2):

> The @PerActivity Scope is supposed to preserve Activity’s dependency instances throughout its lifecycle.

And it does. It creates an annotated dependency in a single component only once.

`AndroidInjection` is just a helper class that knows how to build the component for your Activity / Fragment. It does not store or persist it. Hence...

```
AndroidInjection.inject(this);
```

will create a new component every time it is called and then inject the dependencies. It is not supposed to be called multiple times, and why would you anyways? Just call it *once* in `onCreate` and everything will work fine.

In the case that you *want* to inject twice, you can inject the Activities component itself, and then use the component to inject again. Doing this, using the same component, you should get the same objects every time.

```
@Inject
DoubleInjectActivityComponent component;
```

Just inject it like you would any other dependency.

Comment: There is no specific reason for calling it multiple times other than insuring that the instances are cached properly for each scope. 
In fact, in older dagger approach, one could do such sanity checks (or automated tests) to make sure of that.
It would also ensure that accidental mistakes would not break the application's behavior.

Comment: @Mahorad I don't see why you would do that, but I added an alternative for you to the answer

Comment: Thanks David, Could you elaborate a bit more on  how you define DoubleInjectActivityComponent and glue it to the ApplicationComponent and/or rest of the DI structure?

Comment: @Mahorad That's just an example name. Whatever name your component has that does the injection, you can just inject that component itself. I don't know from the top of my head what the component is called when you use `@ContributesAndroidInjector` but I'm sure you can find out, or just switch to the module with subcomponent variant and name it yourself

Comment: Well, I know the name is arbitrary; rather I was wondering how such a component will work along with @ContributesAndroidInjector which itself creates a subcomponent for the MainActivity injection and links that subcomponent it to its module.